# Measure of the boundary of the support of a certain function defined by an expectation

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, geometric-probability

Suppose:

$\mathcal{S} = \{ S \in \mathbb{R}^d \  | \  S_i > 0, \forall i = 1,...,d  \} $

$R$ is a random vector (on some probability space, $\Omega$) such that, $R: \Omega \to \mathcal{S}$.

$h : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ is compactly supported and continuous on its support such that $m( \partial \text{supp} \ h ) = 0$ where $m$ is $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

$E = \{  x \in \mathbb{R}^d \ | \  c_1 \leq |x| \leq c_2 \}$ where $c_1,c_2 > 0$

---

Let $G: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$G(S) = \mathbb{E}[ h( S \odot R) \ I_{E}(R) ] $

where $S \odot R :=  (S_1 R_1, ..., S_d R_d)$.

Does it follow that $m(\partial \ \text{supp} G) = 0$ ?

---

My thoughts: it is certainly true if $\text{supp} \ h$ is an interval in $\mathbb{R}$. One can compute the support in this case easily. I suppose for higher dimensional problems one will need to construct open covers of arbitrarily small measure, but this seems very difficult...